# backbone jsffidle failed to load external resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
App.module("SampleModule", function(Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y495pz84/

The fiddle load nothing, I checked the path which included they are working files, they did not down. But the console said it must be load with https, I wonder what's wrong there. I found many fiddle down due to the same reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using some deprecated methods from Marionette, please review your use of `addRegion` and `module`. You can review the [correct version of the documentation here](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.1.0/marionette.application.html).

Also, Marionette >3.x (which you're including) depends on [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio). Don't forget to include that in your project as well.

JSFiddle is pretty flimsy and non-straight forward (imho), so I tend to use Plunker instead. I created [a working plunker for you here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDHPoD?p=preview).

Comment: I see white blank screen on ur plunkr

Comment: Yes @Gigilim Since I've commented out the things that wont work. The app starts though and you can see that in the console.